# Telerik radGrid loses selected ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a webform with a Telerik radGrid in which I select a record and then display it in a popup window, but when I press the button to show the record in the form the method does not find the value of the Id and when doing debug I noticed that the radgrid Loses the selected ID. I have other forms with which I do the same procedure but this does not work and I can not find the cause. Thank you in advance for your comments. I am using C # in Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2012.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grdTipoAudi" runat="server" Skin="Sunset" 
   AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowGroupPanel="true" Font-Size="X-Small" Font-
   Names="Arial" OnNeedDataSource="grdTipoAudi_NeedDataSource">

     <MasterTableView NoDetailRecordsText="No existen registros para mostrar." PagerStyle-PageSizeLabelText="Lineas por páginas:" DataKeyNames="idTIPO_AUDITORIA" idTIPO_AUDITORIA">
      <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn"></telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="idTIPO_AUDITORIA" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true"
                                SortExpression="idTIPO_AUDITORIA" UniqueName="idTIPO_AUDITORIA">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="tiaDESCRIPCION" HeaderText="Tipo De Auditoría" ReadOnly="true"
                                SortExpression="tiaDESCRIPCION" UniqueName="tiaDESCRIPCION">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>

                    <ClientSettings>
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

c#

```
protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridDataItem item in grdTipoAudi.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    string strKey = item.GetDataKeyValue("idTIPO_AUDITORIA").ToString();
                }
            }

            IdLinea = "";
            if (grdTipoAudi.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                IdLinea = (grdTipoAudi.SelectedItems[0] as GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("idTIPO_AUDITORIA").ToString();

                SelectTipoAudi(Convert.ToInt32(IdLinea));

                AbrirRadWindow();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just for reference, you can do this all on the client side with the client events, client data keys, and window.radopen()

Comment: Thanks for your intervention. I only know the method that I have published.

Comment: Are you going off of an example or Telerik demo somewhere?

Comment: The problem was that I had not applied the RadAjaxManager to the edit button, as soon as I applied it, I solved the problem. Thank you for your contributions.